# $http and promises and POST

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angular-promise

Given code like the following:

```
function webCall() {
    return $http({ method: "POST", 
                       url: "http://destined/to/fail", data: {param1: 1})
                    .success(function(data, status) { return { test: "success!";} } )
                    .error(function (data, status) { 
                               return {errorMessage: "Totally failed!"};
                     });
```

It is my understanding that if I call .then() on the returned promise like so:

```
var myPromise = webCall().then(
                               function(response){
                                   console.log(response.test);
                               }, 
                               function(reason) {
                                   console.log(reason.errorMessage); 
                               });
```

that the returned value from the appropriate .success() and .error() callbacks is passed along to the .then() callbacks.

I am not seeing the behavior I expect however.  **Using GET it works as expected.** With POST, not so much. Is my assumption that it should act like normal deferred \ promise accurate? Where is it documented (other than the source)

Comment: Your success handler looks like it's missing `return {...}`. Is that just a copy-pasta error?

Comment: This is pseudo code based on working code that I have. Yea I'll fix it.

Comment: should act the same regardless of method

Comment: That's what I am thinking. In my project the GET works like a charm and the POST just passes through what appears to be the same object that was passed to the .success() or .error() callbacks. I'm using 1.2.19 btw.

Comment: I normally use `then` instead of success and error methods

Comment: I have a work around for what I am doing BUT I like to know what the real deal is. I'm guess if this is by design then it is because POSTs don't return data typically.

Comment: I'm digging deeper and it looks like only the success callback passes the data in (for GET). Return values for GET and POST error() don't seem to get passed into then() (but your then will still be called with the data that was in the .success().

Answer (score 0):

`$http()` returns a promise, but what you're returning is actually the result of `.error()`, which isn't a promise (at least it's not documented as such).

To return a promise, you have use `then()`...

```
function webCall() {
    return $http({ method: "POST", 
                   url: "/destined/to/fail", data: {param1: 1})
            .then(function(response) { 
                // if you need to access the data here, use response.data
                return { test: "success!" };
            }, function (response) { 
                throw { errorMessage: "Totally failed!" };
            });
}
```

Note the use of `throw` to reject the returned promise, because if you simply return from the error callback, it actually resolves resulting promise.

Comment: I understand they are not part of the standard interface BUT they work as expected when using GET. So why is the behavior different when using POST? I don't see mention of it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work as you expect is because the `.success` and `.error` handlers return the original promise and it does *nothing* with the return value from the success/error handlers. You can see that from the [source code for $http here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L671).

```
  promise.success = function(fn) {
    promise.then(function(response) {
      fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
    });
    return promise;
  };
```

You can see that once the promise is resolved (when the web call returns), it will call your sucess handler, and then do nothing with it.

When you chain this with other handlers it is the result of the original promise that is passed along to the other handlers.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle using $timeout to simulate the WebCall()?